# Unable to connect Gerrit to Jenkins with Gerrit Trigger plugin, Connection error: com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: Auth fail for methods 'publickey'

Tags: jenkins, cicd, gerrit-trigger

After updating the OS and Jenkins i cant connect to gerrit server by Gerrit Trigger plugin  Connection error : com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: Auth fail for methods 'publickey'

I have verified that the Jenkins account can connect via SSH into the Gerrit server without any problem

Answer (score 1):

The problem was solved by adding into `JAVA_OPT`:

*-Djsch.client_pubkey="ssh-ed25519,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa"
-Djsch.server_host_key="ssh-ed25519,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa"*

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).